# Why join() does not remove empty strings from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

This is a test case of a simple `reactjs` project, where, in this case, I try to test against the `textContent`.

`container` is just a `div` element, which is our render target. And `Simple` is function that returns react component.

`textContent` is string, but the length of the allocated memory and length of the "logical" memory differ from each other. So, first I tried to use `trim()`, which didn't work and thought it was strange, and after I tried to `split()` and `join()`, which is not the best solution, but it should have worked.

```js
it("simple test", function () {
  act(function () {
    const Simple = Template.bind({});
    render(Simple(props), container);
  });
  let received = container.textContent.split(""); // ["A", "B", "C", "", ""]
  received = received.join(""); // "ABC"
  console.log(received.length); // but length is still 5
  let expected = values[0].name; // "ABC", with length 3

  expect(received).toBe(expected); // in conclusion, test case fails
});
```

**EDIT: reproducible example**

both files are in the same directory.

```js
// CurrencyTextField.test.js

import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

import CurrencyTextField from "./CurrencyTextField";

let container = null;
let Template;
let currencies;
let props;
beforeEach(function () {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  props = {
    currencies,
    current: currencies[0],
    handleValueChange: undefined,
    handleCurrencyChange: undefined,
    style: {
      labelWidth: 50,
      classes: { formControl: "" },
    },
    error: { isError: false, errorText: "" },
  };
});

afterEach(function () {
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});

beforeAll(() => {
  Template = (args) => <CurrencyTextField {...args} />;
  currencies = [
    {
      name: "USD",
      flag: "",
      symbo: "$",
      value: "1.54",
      error: {
        isError: false,
        errorText: "",
      },
    },
  ];
});

it("simple test", function () {
  act(function () {
    const Simple = Template.bind({});
    render(Simple(props), container);
  });
  let received = container.textContent.trim(); // here is the problem mentioned above.
  console.log(received);
  console.log(received.length);
  let expected = currencies[0].name;
  expect(received).toBe(expected);
});
```

```js
// CurrencyTextField.js

import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const CurrencyTextField = (props) => {
  const {
    currencies,
    current,
    handleValueChange,
    handleCurrencyChange,
    style,
  } = props;
  const { classes, labelWidth } = style;
  const { formControl } = classes;
  const { name, value } = current;
  const { errorText, isError } = current.error;

  return (
    <FormControl className={formControl} variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel htmlFor={`${name}-currency-value`}>{name}</InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput
        id={`${name}-currency-value`}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleValueChange}
        error={isError}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <TextField select value={name} onChange={handleCurrencyChange}>
              {currencies.map((currency) => (
                <MenuItem key={currency.name} value={currency.name}>
                  {currency.symbol}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        labelWidth={labelWidth | 55}
      />
      <FormHelperText id={`${name}-helper-text`}>{errorText}</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

const _c = PropTypes.shape({
  name: PropTypes.string,
  flag: PropTypes.string,
  symbol: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  error: PropTypes.shape({
    isError: PropTypes.bool,
    errorText: PropTypes.string,
  }),
});

CurrencyTextField.propTypes = {
  currencies: PropTypes.arrayOf(_c),
  current: _c,
  handleValueChange: PropTypes.func,
  handleCurrencyChange: PropTypes.func,
  style: PropTypes.object,
};

export default CurrencyTextField;
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "exchange",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@storybook/cli": "6.1.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "clsx": "1.1.1",
    "money": "0.2.0",
    "nice-color-palettes": "3.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "BROWSER=none start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.18"
  }
}
```

The DOM folding happens because of the `OutlinedInput` component.

And `yarn test` fails.

Comment: It doesn't remove empty strings because it was not designed to do so. You can use `.filter()` to remove elements you don't want, then then `.join()` on that result.

Comment: I can't think of any context where splitting on `""` would result in an array ending in two empty strings. Try providing a [mcve] which includes the input you have to the function.

Comment: `// but length is still 5` – not really reproducible with the code you have shown. The string `ABC` can hardly have length 5, that does not make any sense. The only possible explanation here is that your input data was something else than what you said it was.

Comment: The `textContent` received is string ending with two whitespace characters, which is the result of the folded DOM, like @AKX said, but `trim()` should handle that case, does not it?

Comment: Actually `received = ["A", "B", "C", "", ""]; received.join("").length` outputs 3, not 5

Comment: _“The textContent received is string ending with two whitespace characters”_ - then splitting it at `""` should not get you an array as you have shown it though, you would get two elements containing one white space character each, and not two _empty_ strings instead.

Comment: _“but trim() should handle that case, does not it?”_ - yes, but since you failed to show us how you tried to use it, we can’t tell whether _you_ were able to handle `trim` … Did you take into account that this method _returns_ a new trimmed string, and doesn’t change the original?

Comment: @CBroe, yes I did. I understand that because string is immutable, trimming it results in new string. But I don't know what is problem in this case.

Comment: @CBroe “The textContent received is string ending with two whitespace characters”, my bad, I meant empty strings. I added reproducible example.

Comment: _“my bad, I meant empty strings”_ - that still does not make much sense. How can a string value have “empty strings” at the end? _“I added reproducible example”_ - not going to set up a complete react testing environment now, to reproduce your obscure problem somehow. Maybe you should start by figuring out what your variable _actually_ contains, because right now, it rather sounds like you were guessing. Look at the individual byte values, for example by applying `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: My guess would be, that you are probably mistaking null bytes for “empty strings”, or white space. `trim` does not remove null bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I found.

The two strings received at the end, that I mistakenly thought were empty strings, are actually unicode characters (each with unicode `\u200b`) which are `zero-width space` characters.

So, this is the reason why `trim()`, or `join()` didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such concept as

> the length of the allocated memory and length of the "logical" memory differ from each other

in JavaScript, at least not as far as the user is concerned.

You might be looking for `container.innerText` instead. I think the whitespace you're seeing in `textContent` is a result of otherwise folded DOM whitespace being there, ref.

> For other node types, textContent returns the concatenation of the textContent of every child node, excluding comments and processing instructions.
> – [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Correct the whitespace is the result of the folded DOM, but the question I have is why I can't remove that whitespace later?

Comment: Well, `container.textContent.trim()` should certainly remove it. Are you absolutely sure it's not working?